# Linking a movieclip on the stage to a database entity, Flash AS3 PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, flash, actionscript-3, codeigniter

Does anybody now how i can link an entity on the stage to a database entity in Flash.

Im doing a seating plan and would like to query the database to see if that seat is available or not.
If not then make it un-selectable.

Do i need to give every seat an instance name relating to a row in the DB?

I'll be using PHP, MySQL / XML i think, the rest of my app is built in codeigniter if this sheds any light on the matter for anyone.

any help much appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward actually. 
In your Flash, have a Seat class, which load from your XML (would recommend AMF much nicer).

Assuming XML looking like this:

```
<seatMap>
    <seat available="0" row="23" alley="I"/>
    <seat available="1" row="23" alley="J"/>
    <seat available="0" row="23" alley="K"/>
</seatMap>
```

Main class looking like this:

package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    public function Main() {
        //Code to load XML
    }

    public function onXMLLoaded(e:Event):void {
        var seatMap:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
        for each(var seat:XML in seatMap.seat) {
            var mySeat:Seat = new Seat(seat);
            //Do magic to place seat on stage
            this.addChild(mySeat);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Your seat class should look somewhat like this:

```
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Seat extends MovieClip
    {
        private var _isAvailable:Boolean;
        private var _row:int;
        private var _alley:String;

        public function Seat(seatDef:XML) {
                this._isAvailable = (seatDef.@available !== null)? seatDef.@available : false;
                this._row = seatDef.@row;
                this._alley = seatDef.@alley;

                this._bindListeners(); 
        }

        private function _bindListeners():void {
            if (this._isAvailable) {
                this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, this.onClick);
            }
            //blah
        }

        public function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            //do magic
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow man, thanks so much... theres quite a bit for me to get through there, ill give it a go!

Comment: Hmmm I've been trying to get this working but not having much luck. I'm not that experienced with AS3, Is there a way of me just placing seats on the stage in the order id like and then if they are available in the database then have them clickable, if not available then have some colour change and unclickable?

Comment: Gonna give that a go later, I've not given up doing it the way you originally suggested though... yet